# Given two linear maps $S: V \rightarrow V$ and $T: V \rightarrow V$ such that $ST - TS = I$, prove that $V$ cannot be finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know that a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081444/about-a-problem-of-linear-transformation-st-ts-i) has been asked about this previously. But an [old course](http://math.stanford.edu/~akshay/math113.html) I am currently working through introduces this question as an exercise before concepts such as eigenvalues and characteristic polynomials are introduced. It left me wondering if there is a "simple" way to prove this without needing notions of determinant and characteristic polynomials?

Comment: Is the answer by taking traces that you linked not straightforward enough?

Comment: $V$ need not be infinite-dimensional - it can well be $0$-dimensional

Comment: I suppose it is. The exercise was stated in a lecture regarding the composition of linear maps. The author had just given an example of two linear maps on the vector space $P$ of polynomials with real coefficients: $T(p) =  xp(x)$ and $S(p) = \frac{dp(x)}{d(x)}$. In this case $ST - TS$ is equal to the identity map. All proofs in the course so far are conducted by directly using properties of linear maps rather than by leveraging their matrix representations. So I guess I am curious as to whether there is a proof which does not utiltize the matrix representation of linear maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $V$ is finite dimensional>0, let $Tr$ be the trace of a matrix, we have $Tr(ST)=Tr(TS)$ implies that $Tr(ST-TS)=0$ but $tr(I)=dim(V)$.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from calculating the trace, there's also another solution that gives stronger result. For any $S$, the map $U\mapsto [S,U]$ is a differentiation, that is, it satisfies the Leibnitz rule. Therefore, $[S,T^n]=(n-1)T^{n-1}$. On the other hand, denoting by $||\cdot||$ the operator norm, we have
$||[S,T^n]||\leq ||ST^n||+||T^nS||\leq 2||S||\cdot ||T||\cdot ||T^{n-1}||.$ If there is no $n$ such that $T^{n-1}=0$, then we arrive at a contradiction by taking $n$ large enough. If there is such an $n>2$, then $0=[S,T^{n-1}]=(n-2)T^{n-2}$, and thus also $T^{n-2}=0$, all the way down to $T=0$, which clearly contradicts $[S,T]=I$. Thus, $S$ and $T$ cannot in fact even be bounded operators on a Banach space.